# Are there any dialectological works for Serbia/Serbia & Montenegro/Yugoslavia?

Tags: reference-request, bosnian-croatian-serbian, dialects

I am looking for dialectological works for the area of former Yugoslavia, though I am most interested in Serbia and Montenegro. I can't really find any, other that the kind of maps on wikipedia showing [the division between Štokavian,Čakavian, Kajkavian, Torlak(ian)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSerbo_croatian_dialects_historical_distribution.png), and these maps aren't particularly useful/detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from Rocío, I have found a fairly useful resource (in the bibliography of Greenberg). The reference in question is Pavle Ivić (1958) *Die serbokroatischen Dialekte:ihre Struktur und Entwicklung, Volume 1*. It can be found on [Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Die_serbokroatischen_Dialekte.html?id=tXw0AQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y), but it's not available for preview. However, you might find a copy at a library, I have.

Answer (score 1):

When writing my dissertation about Language and Identity I found these two references:

Bugarski, R. (1997). Lengua, nacionalismo y la desintegración de Yugoslavia. *Revista de Antropología Social, 6,* 13-27.
http://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/RASO/article/download/RASO9797110013A/10187

Greenberg, M. L. (April, 1996). *The role of language in the creation of identity: Myths in linguistics among the people a of the former Yugoslavia.* Article presented at the seminary *Reinvention of Tradition*, University of Kansas.
http://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/dspace/bitstream/1808/969/1/yugoslav_myths96.pdf

Maybe they can help you!

Comment: thanks for your help, while these examples are useful, they didn't give much of an insight regarding some hard evidence for the dialectology. However, in the references to Greenberg, I did find something that was useful, so I'll post it as an answer :) +1